# preg_replace or mb_ereg_replace in this case?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, preg-replace, multibyte

I have this RegEx for matching whitespace in Unicode:

```
/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u
```

I'm not even sure of what it does, but it seems to work. Now, in this case, which function applies better and why?

```
$str = preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u', '', $str);
```

or

```
$str = mb_ereg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one works. The second one doesn't.

Tried it out again, [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://php.net/mb_ereg_replace) **doesn't** actually support those Unicode char escapes. And it doesn't use regex delimiters. (See [Oniguruma](http://www.google.com/search?q=Oniguruma))

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) uses the PCRE regex engine, which supports both.

---

Anyway, there is no such thing as a "better" application. It's either functioning, or not.

Comment: Oh, okay then. I thought that mb_ereg_replace, being a multibyte-secure function would work with Unicode, but I guess I was wrong. Thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: Actually it should support `\p{Any}` escapes. Being multibyte-string aware is one of the selling points of `Oniguruma`. But for some silly reason it doesn't work in PHP. http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/oniguruma/files/Syntax_txt.html

Comment: That's strange. Then it _should_ work, but due to a bug it doesn't? Anyways, preg_replace worked for me so I'll stick with it. Unless there's a reason to use multibyte functions in this case

Comment: If you have UTF-8 strings, then `preg_replace` is the advisable option. (Because that's the only charset it understands). The `mb_` ones only make sense when you have a more uncommon encoding (UTF-16 or what).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find more information about these functions and it seems that a key difference between preg_replace and mb_ereg_replace/mb_eregi_replace is that the latter does not use / to enclose the pattern. The test in the question should have been created like this: `$str = mb_ereg_replace('^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$', '', $str);`

The weird part was that this information does not seem to be in php docs themselves but in the user's comments.